# Angular2 injecting components

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, angular

I have a modal-component wrapped in an *ngIf inside another component. Can i inject this component into the parent so that I can access the instance. The modal-component has a show and hide method that toggles the *ngIf flag. What is the most appropriate way to accomplish this? I dont want to use jquery or elementRef.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by inject it into it's parent?

Comment: Do you just want access to the data available in the modal to be accessed by the parent?

Comment: 1. import modal-component in desired component code file.
2. pass the component name in 'provider' in parent component declaration.

Comment: Please show us some code or efforts you've taken to accomplish this.

Comment: It looks like the Viewchild api is what I am after - possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018478/getting-a-reference-to-the-child-component-in-the-parent-component.......is the viewchild an acceptable, unit testable construct?