# How to get Children component like in React's this.props.children in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

How can I build a container component which can access child component like React's this.props.children?

Comment: You could use `@ViewChildren`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36018562/5115768

Comment: @lenny Thanks but I did not quite get it, since what I build is a container component, I did not know what child a user will put inside, how can I access that?(I thought ViewChild is used to refer to a Child which already specified in the template)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

in React you do

```
const Comp = ({ children }) => (
    <div class="wrapper">{children}</div>
);
```

in Angular2 you do

```
@Component({
    selector: 'comp',
    template: `
        <div class="wrapper"><ng-content></ng-content></div>
    `
})
class Comp {}
```

Comment: how to get this in angularjs? any idea

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `@ViewChildren` inside your component to access children placed inside the component.

Also, you want to decide where children are placed inside your template, you need to place an `<ng-content></ng-content>` somewhere in your template.