# How to use JS property like "offsetWidth" in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get the width of an element using JS in my Angular app.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("element")[0].offsetWidth;
```

When I do this i am getting the below compilation error

> Property 'of
>   fsetWidth' does not exist on type 'Element'.

Could someone tell me how to use it in Angular 4.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If give identification of your DOM element using #

### Template:

```
<div class="for-example" #titleText>For Example</div>
```

### Component:

Declare

```
@ViewChild('titleText') titleTextElement;
```

and get offsetWidth like following:

```
this.titleTextElement.nativeElement.offsetWidth
```

Comment: Thank you. 
One more doubt. How can I access child component reference variable in parent component

Comment: Check this out for your doubt.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018478/getting-a-reference-to-the-child-component-in-the-parent-component